# Linux, reraging partition order

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have disk formatted in the following way:

```
(EFI)
(Windows Partition) - (Windows recovery)
(NTFS Partition For My Files)
(Linux Partition)
```

The problem is that I resize/split my data partition quite often for testing purposes and haveing to move/resize my linux partition is just absolute hassle, because it has around ~400GB of data.
So that's why I want to rearange them.
Is there some way/tool to do it, preferably one that works in terminal?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. Why do you want to rearrange the partitions?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Edited my question.

Comment: Why do you need to move the Linux partition? Why not leave it at the end of the disk?

Comment: Well, I usually have a lot of date on linux partition and shrinking it for a moment from RIGHT is easier than shring and move to right.

Comment: Why not add an extra partition that you can share between Linux and Windows?

Comment: This data is mostly binaries for linux so there is no point in sharing them with windows.
But I would like to get straight to the answer, is there way to rearrange partitions, or not?